# RequiredFieldValidator for dropdownlist not work

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

what I do wrong?

```
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlProductUnits" runat="server" Width="100%">


         <asp:Repeater ID="repProductUnits" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" onitemcommand="Button_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="grid" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">test1</th>
        <th align="left">test2</th>
        <th align="left">test3</th>
        <th width="50"></th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td><%# ((DBData.Catalog.ProductU)Container.DataItem).PrimaryUnitName%>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    <%# ((DBData.Catalog.ProductU)Container.DataItem).SecondaryUnitName%>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    <%# ((DBData.Catalog.ProductU)Container.DataItem).Quantity%>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none">
    <asp:Label ID="PrimaryUnitID" runat="server" 
     Text="<%# ((DBData.Catalog.ProductU)Container.DataItem).PrimaryUnitID%>">
   </asp:Label>
   <asp:Label ID="SecondaryUnitID" runat="server" 
    Text="<%# ((DBData.Catalog.ProductU)Container.DataItem).SecondaryUnitID%>">
   </asp:Label>
</td>
<td align="center">

  <asp:Button id="btRemove"  runat="server" commandname="deleteProductUnit" Text="Delete"> 
  </asp:Button>
  </td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<tr>
   <td>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrimaryUnit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="grpQuantity">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" 
   Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ControlToValidate="ddlPrimaryUnit" ValidationGroup="grpQuantity" ForeColor="#FF3300"> 
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSecondaryUnit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="grpQuantity">
            </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ControlToValidate="ddlSecondaryUnit" ValidationGroup="grpQuantity" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
  <td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" placeholder="select value" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"  ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" ValidationGroup="grpQuantity" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
       <td colspan="20">
   <asp:Button id="btNew"  runat="server" commandname="addProductUnit" Text="Add" 
    CommandArgument="test" ValidationGroup="grpQuantity"> </asp:Button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Worked for me. What isn't working for you?

Comment: Add ValidationGroup="grpQuantity" to the dropdown list also and check

Comment: @KiranHegde I added, but not work

Comment: @BubbleHearth this ddl is in footer of repeater, maybe this can be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it definitely could be. Could you please update your question with your full page source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is related to the validator knowing what the DropDownList's original selection was and whether or not something has been selected. You may need to add an `InitialValue` to the required field validator.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
     runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" 
     ControlToValidate="ddlSecondaryUnit" ValidationGroup="grpQuantity" 
     ForeColor="#FF3300" InitialValue=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Depending on your DropDownList's datasource, that value may be something like "Please Select" or maybe just blank.

Comment: Ok, well you still haven't told us exactly what doesn't work. What are you expecting to happen and what is happening?

Comment: Sorry, what? The "*" error message is never displayed? Is that what you mean?

Comment: when I click on button the error message doesn't display, and click event send dates to server

Comment: Ok, and what does the datasource to your DropDownList look like? What is its initial value? Could you possibly post some screenshots of what the screen looks like when you click the "Add" button and it doesn't work?